# Adding publish_action permission and posting on wall

Tags: android, facebook

I have an Activity which has two buttons

1. Is for logging into facebook. After Login I finish that Activity
2. Other button is for posting on to the wall

The first part I did Ok but for the second part I reffered facebook samples and tried to add posting permission to my open session as follows

```
private void performPublish(PendingAction action) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        pendingAction = action;
        if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            // We can do the action right away.
            handlePendingAction();
        } else {
            // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS));
        }
    }
}
```

but I got the following errors

```
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartcloud/com.smartcloud.HelloFacebookSampleActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1751)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1767)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1005)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4028)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPermissions(Session.java:968)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPublishPermissions(Session.java:501)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at com.smartcloud.HelloFacebookSampleActivity.performPublish(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java:194)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at com.smartcloud.HelloFacebookSampleActivity.onClickPostStatusUpdate(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java:161)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at com.smartcloud.HelloFacebookSampleActivity.onCreate(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java:89)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1715)
    04-14 16:49:18.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2529):     ... 11 more
```

Please Help me out! Its really very Important to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait till the `session` is open before requesting new permissions. You can use a [statusCallback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session.StatusCallback) and check when the session is open (in the `call` method) and after that, request new permissions.